# Passing values between view(fxml) and controller in javafx

Tags: javafx, fxml

My task is to call a single method on clicking 3 buttons in javafx and that particular method execute the code that simply change the color of the button which is clicked.

According to the scene i have created 3 buttons in fxml and inside my controller i have defined a method. The code for my task is simply

```
myButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color:green");
```

Now would you please tell me that how can i get that particular button id that is clicked.
Here **myButton** is the **fx:id** of the button that is clicked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can define a `onAction="#methodName"` for each button as shown in [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm#CIAEDJBA)

Comment: that'a ok but how to pass the fx:id of that button to the controller

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
@FXML
public void handleActionEvent(ActionEvent event) {
   Object source = event.getSource();
   if (source.equals(buttonA)) {
      buttonA.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
   } else if (source.equals(buttonB)) {
      buttonB.setStyle("-fx-background-color:green");
   } else if (source.equals(buttonC)) {
      buttonC.setStyle("-fx-background-color:blue");
   }
}
```

Having three buttons within your controller:

```
@FXML
private Button buttonA;

@FXML
private Button buttonB;

@FXML
private Button buttonC;
```

Each button needs the accordant `id` and `onAction="#handleActionEvent"` within the fxml.

Answer (score 0):

`fx:id`'s are never passed to the controller. Instead they are used to inject the control's instance into the controller when your fxml gets loaded via the FXMLLoader.

When your fxml has a control

```
<Button fx:id="myButton">
```

You need to make sure that the Button reference that you create inside you controller should have the same name. If not, the instantiation of the Button will fail.

```
public class MyController {

   @FXML
   private Button myButton; // name should be same as the fx:id 
   ...
}
```

Similarly, if you want to add an action on the button, you can add it on the FXML,

```
<Button fx:id="myButton" onAction="#myAction">
```

And this will look for a method with the same name in the controller. Whenever you click the button it will call the method defined in the controller.

```
public class MyController {

   @FXML
   private Button myButton; // name should be same as the fx:id 
   ...

   public void myAction(ActionEvent event) {
       // Do Something 
   }
}
```